# Degree $2$ nilpotent matrices with non-zero product

Tags: number-theory, matrices

Let $n$ be sufficiently large positive integer.

Let $M_i$ be $n$ matrices with entries in either $\mathbb{C}$
or $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$.

> Is it possible, (1) for $1 \le i \le n, M_i^2=0$ and
>   (2) every product of the permutations of $M_i$ doesn't vanish: $\prod_{i} M_i \ne 0$?

If it is possible, $M_i$ better be as small as possible.

Explicit construction for single $n$ as large as possible is of
interest to me.

---

For $n=3$ solution exists with 3 by 3 matrices,
coming from parametrization of nilpotent matrices.

In flattened form:

```
 M1=[-59/20, -767/400, -59/400, 3, 39/20, 3/20, 20, 13, 1]
 M2=[-441, -8379, -93933, 12, 228, 2556, 1, 19, 213]
 M3=[-1931, -17379, -44413, 212, 1908, 4876, 1, 9, 23]
```

Comment: [[0,1], [0,0]] and [[0,0], [1,0]]... You should ask on math.stackexchange, this is not a research level question...

Comment: @DanielJuteau Thanks. Yours are only $2$ and I want $n$ matrices. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Alternating those two matrices?

Comment: Use Jordan canonical form.   But as Daniel suggests, this is not a research level question.

Comment: OK, I don't mind this downvoted and/or closed, but I still don't see solution. Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not satisfied by ABABABABA..., where A and B are the matrices in my first comment, then maybe you forgot to mention some other properties you would like the matrices to satisfy?

Comment: @DanielJuteau Thanks :) Indeed I wanted something else:  every product of permutations must not vanish.

Comment: @DanielJuteau I edited asking for permutations, which appears to break your solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok. Makes more sense. One should never use the Pi product notation in a noncommutative context! :)

Comment: @DanielJuteau Indeed, my mistake :-(. Is there known parametrization for degree 2 nilpotent like my solution for n=3?

Comment: Yes. I will give an answer in dimension 2 for any $n$.

Comment: And if one allows dimension $n + 1$, of course you can take $n$ matrices all equal to a single Jordan block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general nilpotent matrix in dimension 2 can be written in the form
$$M(v):=\begin{pmatrix} xy & -x^2 \\ y^2 & -xy\end{pmatrix}, \quad v=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$ The best is to interpret $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ as $\mathfrak{sp}(V,\omega)$ where $(V,\omega)$ is a $2$-dimensional symplectic space. Then one has a natural isomorphism $\phi:V\to V^*$, and the matrix above, with suitable choice of the form, represents the map which corresponds to $v \otimes \phi(v)$ for some $v\in V$ (viewing endomorphisms as $V\otimes V^*$). Take matrices of this form with vectors $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$ such that $\omega(v_i, v_j) \neq 0$ for $i\neq j$ (if you want to do that for all $n$, this requires the field to be infinite).

Comment: Many thanks :) This is another question, but do think solution in any dimension is possible with the restriction every subproduct to not depend on the order of the matrices? Commutativity hurt me again.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^{ij}$, where $1\leq i,j\leq n$, be $n\times n$ matrices with elements given by
$$
(A^{ij})_{ab} = \delta_{ia}(1-\delta_{jb}),
$$
where $\delta$ is Kronecker delta. In other words, the matrix $A^{ij}$ is filled with zeros, except for its $i$-th row, which is filled with ones, except for its $j$-th place, which is again zero. Then
$$
A^{ij}A^{kl} = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if} ~~j=k;\\ A^{il}& \text{if} ~~j\neq k.\end{cases}
$$

Set $M_i = A^{ii}$. Then $M_i^2 = 0$ and $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n M_{i_k} = A^{i_1i_n}$ if $i_1\neq i_2\neq \dots \neq i_n$.

Comment: Many thanks :) This is another question, but do think solution in any dimension is possible with the restriction every subproduct to not depend on the order of the matrices? Commutativity hurt me again.

Comment: @joro : "every subproduct to not depend on the order of the matrices" — do you mean that the matrices commute with each other?

Comment: I am trying to prepare new question. Probably yes, they need to commute. For all subsets $t$ of $\{M_i\}$, I want $\prod_{M \in t} M$ to not depend of the ordering of $t$.

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to matrices commuting with each other. If your condition is true, then we can see that the matrices commute by looking at all 2-element $t$. And if matrices commute, then we can transform any ordering of a product into any other ordering by switching places of neighboring matrices (for example, $ABC=ACB=CAB=CBA=BCA=BAC$).

Comment: Asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249763/degree-2-nilpotent-matrices-with-non-zero-product-and-subset-products-not-depe). Feel free to edit or suggest edits if you parse the question.